# Apache rewrite engine for image proxying

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, proxy

Requests look like "/logos/***(prefix + md5 hash)***" (prefix is the first char)
For example /logos/012330293949292332

The htaccess config should do the following:

split ***(prefix + md5 hash)*** to ***prefix*** and ***md5 hash***

return logo if ***md5 hash***.png is in folder /logos/default

return logo if ***prefix***.* is in folder /logos/custom/***hash***

My current solution works with php as image proxy but this is not fast enough so is this possible with apache rewrite engine and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/logos/default/$2.png -f
RewriteRule ^logos/(.)(.+)$     /images/logos/default/$2.png [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/logos/custom/$2/$1.png -f
RewriteRule ^logos/(.)(.+)$     /images/logos/custom/$2/$1.png [NC,L]
```